# Why aren't my XSLT variables substituting their values?

Tags: xslt, variables, substitution

I am trying to use XSLT variables and not having much success, hopefully I'm just doing something dumb.

I have the following code snippet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
  version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="config" select="query/@config"></xsl:variable>
```

so I expect there to be a variable 'config' set to the value of the 'config' attribute of my top-level element 'query'.

I then try to use the variable later in my stylesheet, for example:

```
<a href="localhost/test?go">
    {$config}
</a>
```

but the output I see in my output HTML document is:

```
<a href="localhost/test?go">
    {$config}
</a>
```

so the value has not been substituted as I would have expected.

I think this is pretty much the simplest case there could be, so I'm doing domething stupid! Please help, thanks!

---

UPDATE thanks to all who responded, I misunderstood the different contexts of whether I was working in an attribute or outside. Sorted my problem out nicely!

If I could I would accept two answers, the one I have, and @Aaron Digulla's, which explained the attributes thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your stylesheet you must use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$config"/>
```

instead of:

```
{$config}
```

Answer (score 13):

There are two questions here that seem the same, but which are subtly different: 1) *How* do I reference a variable by name? 2) *Where* can I reference a variable by name?

First, variables are always referenced using the `$varname` syntax. Second, this can be done *anywhere an expression is allowed*. It's the second part of this that seems to confuse. To start with, the value of an element or attribute will by default be output literally, so no variables are actually referenced in the following example:

```
<element attr="$test">$test or {$test}</element>
```

The output will literally match what was typed.

To output a variable's value, we need to reference it where an expression is allowed. In element content, we use `xsl:value-of`; in attributes that are treated as an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) (e.g. the attributes of a literal result element), expressions are delimited by curly braces `{}`. Assume the following declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="'value'"/>
```

...then the following:

```
<element attr="{$test}"><xsl:value-of select="$test"/></element>
```

...results in:

```
<element attr="value">value</element>
```

A few parting notes on AVTs and `value-of`:

- In both cases the variable was referenced as `$test`. The braces in an AVT are not part of the variable reference; they are expression delimiters.
- In either case, the expression need not have contained a reference to a variable; any XPath expression would have been allowed.
- Not all attributes in an XSLT document are treated as attribute value templates. For example, notice that `xsl:value`'s `select` attribute *already accepts an expression* as content.
- **Question**: Why can't you use `value-of` in an attribute, like this?

  ```
  <element attr="<xsl:value-of select="$test"/>"/>
  ```

  **Answer**: Because XSLT documents must contain well-formed XML (and that isn't).
- **Question**: Why can't you use `{$varname}` in element content?

  **Glib answer**: because XSLT's creators didn't design it that way.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I added re: the last question/answer in your answer. Not sure if you've seen this yet (since your answer is so old).

Comment: Thanks for so clearly explaining the different syntaxes for referencing variables in different places.  I found this while searching for explanation on the {} syntax.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`{$config}` only works in attributes of XSLT elements. (Note: dollar inside the brace because the complete XPath expression must be surrounded by braces)

Comment: Why would the $ need to be in front of the opening brace? Never seen that.

Comment: @divo: because that's the syntax.

Comment: (continued) "In an attribute value that is interpreted as an attribute value template [...] an expression can be used by surrounding the expression with curly braces ({})."

Comment: Well, you showed me. That's what I get for trusting an answer on SO, I guess. I'll never make that mistake again!

Comment: Holy *)%*&/ I'd have sworn that it was ${} (just like anywhere else). No wonder XSLT is so unpopular ;)

Comment: @divo: I just read the link and ... I didn't understand it :P I mean, it's English and all but ... they don't really care whether anyone can get what they say, do they? ;)

Comment: @AaronDigulla - You were confused about the syntax `{$varname}` because you were thinking about it wrong. `$varname` is how you reference the variable. The brackets delimit an Attribute Value Template, the contents of which might not even contain a variable, in which case there would be no `$` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="$config"/>` instead of `{$config}`.

Comment: @Kezzer: That's why they pay me the big bucks <('_'<)

Answer (score 2):

@lwburk's answer is great (+1), but the last question/answer is only accurate for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0. In 3.0 you can use a TVT ([Text Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates); similar to the AVT (Attribute Value Template) mentioned in @lwburk's answer).

To use a TVT, add the standard attribute `xsl:expand-text="yes"` to the element. This will cause the processor to treat descendant text nodes of that element as a TVT.

Example:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="who" select="'Dan'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="what" select="'BAM!'"/>
        <result xsl:expand-text="yes">This is {$who}'s result: {$what}</result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (using any well-formed XML as input)

```
<result>This is Dan's result: BAM!</result>
```

*Note: Tested using Saxon-PE 9.5.*

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to use `<xsl:value-of select="config"/>` ?

Comment: If config is a variable, we must use $config, no?