# How do I use the value of XSLT variables?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to learn XSLT. I am simply getting crazy. Variables should be declared within xsl:variables entity and instantiated with their names having the $ symbol just before them (like perl variables), right? Why on earth this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="color" select="'red'" />
        <p>$color</p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

results in the literal string: "$color" being written parsing a simple non empty xml document using the msxsl parser? Many thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="$color"/>` instead of writing `$color` directly to the document.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634295/why-arent-my-xslt-variables-substituting-their-values).

Answer (score 11):

Also, within attributes you can get to the values directly like this:

```
<span style="color:{$color}" />
```

Comment: +1 - all these years I've been using <xsl:attribute> to do this - why did nobody tell me before!

Comment: ditto... and the worst part is, I've seen it before and forgot.  :(

Comment: Glad to spread some joy - @Phil, your words are quite similar to mine when I discovered this too!

Answer (score 2):

> Why on earth this code: ...
>
> `<xsl:variable name="color"
>   select="'red'" />
>           <p>$color</p>`
>
> results in the literal string:
>   "$color" being written

**Because this code means: output the string $color as the text node child of the `<p>` element**.

To output the value of the `$color` xsl:variable use one of these:

- **`<xsl:value-of select="$color"/>`**
- **`<xsl:copy-of select="$color"/>`**

Answer (score 2):

A good rule of thumb for xslt: if it's not in an `<xsl:foo>` tag, it's not code. It's output.