# How to debug errors in Sharepoint XSL?

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

```
<xsl:template match="Row">                                 
    <div id="listitem-{@ID}">
        <div class="<xsl:value-of select="@Col-md" /> ">
            <div class="features-item text-center">
                <div class="features-icon">
                    <img>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Picture" /></xsl:attribute></img>
                </div>
                <h3 class="features-title font-alt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
                </h3>
                <div class="features-descr">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                </div>                  

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm new to XSLT. I have created a SharePoint list field name `Col-md` containing the bootstrap column values, e.g. `col-Md-6`, `col-md-4`, `col-md-3`. I'm passing the values like this `<div class="<xsl:value-of select="@Col-md" /> ">` XSLT but I get errors.

Comment: "I get errors" is not a good description of a problem. You are already using [the `{}` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22106054/11683) in `<div id="listitem-{@ID}">`, you should do the same in `<div class="">`.

Comment: Thank you GSerg, It's work like a charm :)

Comment: If it works like a charm, does that mean it doesn't work? Put the errors in that you're getting. This is presently missing an [mcve], so may be put on hold.