# How to create a value which can be repeatedly used throughout XSLT code?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create a value which can be used throughout a complete xslt document. I'm pretty close I think, but can't get it work.

The basis of my XML:

```
<items>
 <item>
  <name>Test xslt</name>
  <code>XSLT</code>
   <description>
   <description1>1x stay</description1>
   <description2>1x breakfast</description2>
   <description3>1x diner</description3>
   <description4>1x free late check-out</description1>
   <address>New York 1234AZ</address>
  </description>
  <url>https://www.myurl.com/hotels/exampleurl</url>
 </item>
 <item>
  <name>Test xslt 2</name>
  <code>XSLT 2</code>
   <description>
   <description1>1x stay</description1>
   <description2>1x breakfast</description2>
   <description3>1x diner</description3>
   <description4>1x free late check-out</description1>
   <address>New York 1234AZ</address>
  </description>
  <url>https://www.myurl.com/vakantiepark/exampleurl</url>
 </item>
</itemss>
```

This is my (not complete) XSLT now:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:call-template name="item" />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template name="item"> 
 <xsl:for-each select="item">
  <xsl:if test="position() = '1'">
   <xsl:if test="url[contains(text(),'/hotel/')]">
    <xsl:variable name="color">#EC008C</xsl:variable> 
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="url[contains(text(),'/vakantiepark/')]">
    <xsl:variable name="color">#F58220</xsl:variable>
   </xsl:if>
   <th valign="top" align="left" class="pu padding-bottom-30-m">
    <table width="340" class="y" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;padding: 0">
     <tr class="hide-for-small">
      <td style="padding-bottom: 10px">
         <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '1 ster'"> <span style="font-size: 16px; color: $usecolorhere;">★</span></xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '2 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px; color: $usecolorhere;">★★</span></xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '3 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px; color: $usecolorhere;">★★★</span></xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '4 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px; color: $usecolorhere;"></span></xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '5 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px; color: $usecolorhere;">★★★★★</span></xsl:if>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
       <span style="background-color: $usecolorhere;color: #fff;font-family: 'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 700!important;line-height: 18px;margin: 0;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;padding: 0;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px; border-radius:2px;">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(custom_fields/review_average, 1,3)" />
       </span>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </th>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've marked where i want to use the variable with `$usecolorhere`. So based on whether the URL contains `/hotels/` or `/vakantiepark/` I want to used a different color for all colored elements in the HTML structure. Does anyone know how to easily create a variable like this and re-use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this template:

```
  <xsl:template name="item"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
      <xsl:if test="position() = '1'">
        <xsl:variable name="colorInStyle">
          <xsl:variable name="textUrl" select="url/text()"/>
          <xsl:if test="contains($textUrl,'/hotel/') or contains($textUrl,'/vakantiepark/')">
            <xsl:text> color: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="contains($textUrl,'/hotel/')">#EC008C</xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>#F58220</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>
        <th valign="top" align="left" class="pu padding-bottom-30-m">
          <table width="340" class="y" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;padding: 0">
            <tr class="hide-for-small">
              <td style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '1 ster'"> <span style="font-size: 16px;{$colorInStyle}">★</span></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '2 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px;{$colorInStyle}">★★</span></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '3 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px{$colorInStyle}">★★★</span></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '4 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px{$colorInStyle}"></span></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="custom_fields/ratings = '5 sterren'"> <span style="font-size: 16px{$colorInStyle}">★★★★★</span></xsl:if>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <span style="background-color: $usecolorhere;color: #fff;font-family: 'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 700!important;line-height: 18px;margin: 0;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;padding: 0;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px; border-radius:2px;">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring(custom_fields/review_average, 1,3)" />
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </th>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

$colorInStyle wil only have a style-property if it fulfills the options for the url. And if so adds the correct color-values to it.

And to use a variable [inside a attribute you need to use curly braces around that variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106562/3710053).

**EDIT**

if you can be certain that there either will be a hotel or vakantiepark in the url and there `ratings` always start with a number from 1 to 5 , this template would be the way to go (using xsl:choose in stead of xsl:if)

```
  <xsl:template name="item"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <th valign="top" align="left" class="pu padding-bottom-30-m">
          <table width="340" class="y" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0;mso-table-rspace: 0;padding: 0">
            <tr class="hide-for-small">
              <td style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                <xsl:variable name="color">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(url/text(),'/hotel/')">#EC008C</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>#F58220</xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <span style="font-size: 16px;color: {$color};">
                  <xsl:variable name="firstCharRatings" select="substring(custom_fields/rating,1,1)"/>
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstCharRatings = '1'">
                      <xsl:text>★</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstCharRatings = '2'">
                      <xsl:text>★★</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstCharRatings = '3'">
                      <xsl:text>★★★</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstCharRatings = '4'">
                      <xsl:text>★★★★</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$firstCharRatings = '5'">
                      <xsl:text>★★★★★</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <span style="background-color: $usecolorhere;color: #fff;font-family: 'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 700!important;line-height: 18px;margin: 0;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;padding: 0;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px; border-radius:2px;">
                  <xsl:value-of select="substring(custom_fields/review_average, 1,3)" />
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </th>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly, you could replace :

```
<xsl:template name="item"> 
 <xsl:for-each select="item">
  <xsl:if test="position() = '1'">
   <xsl:if test="url[contains(text(),'/hotel/')]">
    <xsl:variable name="color">#EC008C</xsl:variable> 
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="url[contains(text(),'/vakantiepark/')]">
    <xsl:variable name="color">#F58220</xsl:variable>
   </xsl:if>
...
... 
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

By this

```
<xsl:template name="item"> 
 <xsl:variable name="color">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="url[contains(text(),'/hotel/')]">
    #EC008C
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="url[contains(text(),'/vakantiepark/')]">
    #F58220
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    #FFFFFF
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:variable>
  ...
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Your template treat every "item" independently so you don't need a for-each.