# how to set namespace using a Param to my root node in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a payload as below:

```
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
<CompoundEmployee>
    <name>tester</name>
    <person_id_external>12345</person_id_external>
</CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

I would like to add a namespace say "myNamespace/2019-10".

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse xmlns="myNamespace/2019-10">
<CompoundEmployee>
<name>tester</name>
<person_id_external>12345</person_id_external>
</CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

Below is XSL I have tried with param - param1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:hci="http://sap.com/it/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="hci">

    <xsl:param name="param1"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="$param1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it the right way to set namespace using **param1** xsl:param ?
please correct me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Well, if you look how you are setting the name, you can just do the same with the namespace... `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$param1}">`

Comment: What @TimC said. Plus you have a lot of redundant code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -- Can you suggest me what piece of code is redundant. I can remove it.

Comment: @TimC -- Thanks a lot for suggesting. Now I made the correction and it works :) Can you add as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't my XSLT variables substituting their values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634295/why-arent-my-xslt-variables-substituting-their-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you suggest me what piece of code is redundant. I can remove it.

All you need to handle the given XML is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="param1"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$param1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you expect the input to have attributes too, add:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
```

before:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

Answer (score 0):

plz add value `<xsl:param name="param1" select="'myNamespace/2019-10'"/>` insted of `<xsl:param name="param1"/>`

Code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:hci="http://sap.com/it/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="hci">

    <xsl:param name="param1" select="'myNamespace/2019-10'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" priority="1">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$param1}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The idea of a `param` is that it will be populated at runtime.